# How can I center four image views in Android ConstraintLayout without knowing parent view dimensions?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I would like to center four image views in an Android ConstraintLayout. Assume that I don't know the width and height of the parent view, whether it's in landscape or portrait mode. It's difficult to explain verbally, so let me show you an image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp5SF.png)

Each image should be aligned to the center of the parent view, while maintaining their aspect ratio.

I aligned the width and height of each image to the center and sides of the parent view, setting them to match_parent. Then, I used the scaleType options fitStart and fitEnd to position the bottom-right and top-left images as desired. However, since there is no fitRightTop and fitLeftBottom options available, I ultimately failed to achieve the desired placement for those images.

--edit1--

@Samuel Robert's response yielded the following results.

[Samuel Robert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp3Pm.png)

However, what I desire is to have the image centered, as shown in the top-left and bottom-right images of the following illustration.

[I desire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya9tu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 guildlines:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/h_gl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/v_gl"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>
```

And put your images to top/left/bottom/right of them.

Comment: I've already done that, but I've completely failed to produce the results I want.

Comment: Try this :For example with image 1 ( red stroke).  width = 0dp, height = wrapcontent, bottomToTopOf : h_gl, startToStartOf: parent, end to Start of : v_gl

Answer (score 0):

While you can constrain your views with guidelines as suggested by Duy, there is another way to form a chain which has the same effect.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/image3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@color/purple_200"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/image4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@color/teal_200"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image2" />
```

The result would look like this for portrait[image: portrait]

and for landscape [image: landscape]